# Good book on PCI DSS?

Tags: pci-dss, professional-education, compliance, payment

I need to upgrade my skills on PCI DSS Compliance. I'm looking for a couple of combo: one to cover everything in an extensive way (a sort on encyclopedia to keep as a reference) and a quick guide to keep with me at work.

Any recommendations?

Comment: why not go directly to the source and read from PCI itself??

Answer (score 1):

You can't really go wrong with the PCI Security Standards Council document library:

[PCI SSC document library](https://www.pcisecuritystandards.org/document_library)

The standard itself is thorough and contains plenty of guidance for each of the controls.

There are also a handful of other specific guidance documents, for example currently the list includes cloud computing guidance, guide to risk assessment etc.

Your relevant SAQ could form the basis of a quick reference.